# BitmapImage BackgroundCreation in WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

In WP8, BitmapCreateOptions include value Background Creation, this help create image in Background. I working with contacts, a lot of avatar, so it is necessary to increase performance.
But, in Windows-runtime/ WP8.1, there is no Background Creation. Please help me

> bitmap.CreateOptions =
> BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
>
> bitmap.SetSource(source);

.....

```
<Ellipse Width="70" Height="70">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding bitmap}" /> 
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: are you sure that you have given the correct model property to your imagesource binding?